# Is there any macro to check if -lrt switch is specified during a g++ compile?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

Is there any test macro that can be used to see if the code is being compiled with the `-lrt` switch (POSIX.1b Realtime Extensions library)? I would like to use it in my code around sections using `clock_gettime`, so that it is not used if `-lrt` was not specified during the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lXXX` is a linker flag; it's only relevant *after* compilation and preprocessing have occurred.  So no, there is no macro that can do this.

Comment: Darn, so basically, there is no way to test at compile time whether I can use clock_gettime instead of gettimeofday...

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: I don't think so.  There may be some clever linker hackery that you could do, but I have no idea what it would involve!